# Using button to retrieve data from XML

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom

I have made a code in which on clicking computer Science button I get data from XML

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="loadxmldoc.js"></script>
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="text-align:center">DEPARTMENT DETAILS</h1>
<button onclick="myfunction()">Computer Science</button>
</br>
<script>
function myfunction(){
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("faculty.xml");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("computer")[0];
var y=x.childNodes;
for(i=0;i<y.length;i++)
 document.write(y[i].nodeName+"&nbsp&nbsp"+y[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</br>"); 
}
 </script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

When I click on button I do get the data but a new page is loaded. I would like to have data below the button. How to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.write` is archaic and useful only before the DOM has loaded. If it's used after that, it overwrites the current DOM, as you've discovered.

Use DOM methods instead and prepare a container to receive the content.

HTML:

```
<div id='container'></div>
```

JS:

```
var cntr = document.querySelector('#container'), html = '';
for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    html += y[i].nodeName+"&nbsp&nbsp"+y[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</br>"; 
}
cntr.innerHTML = html;
```

Comment: Completely agree with document.write is archaic :-)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using this approach.

Basically load your xml data, and display the result in a div "result";

```
  <html>
    <head>
    <script src="loadxmldoc.js"></script>
     </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1 style="text-align:center">DEPARTMENT DETAILS</h1>
    <button onclick="myfunction()">Computer Science</button>
    </br>
    <script>
    function myfunction(){
    xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("faculty.xml");
    var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("computer")[0];
    var y=x.childNodes;
    var result = document.getElementById('result');
    for(i=0;i<y.length;i++)
    result.innerHTML = ''; // always reset
    result.innerHTML +='y[i].nodeName+"&nbsp&nbsp"+y[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</br>"';
     //document.write(y[i].nodeName+"&nbsp&nbsp"+y[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</br>"); 
    }
     </script>
     <div id="result"></div>
      </body>
     </html>
```